# How do I combine -I and -n with xargs?

Tags: linux, xargs

I want to move a large set of files using `find` and `xargs`. Normally I'd do this:

```
find /foo -name 'bar*' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs -I % echo mv % /dest
```

However, when there are too many files to move, I hit the limit of the number of arguments to pass to `mv`. `xargs` has a `-n` which seems like it would be perfect for this:

```
$ echo {0..9} | xargs -n 3 echo
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9
```

However, `-I` implies `-L 1`, so I can't use `-I` with `-n`:

```
$ echo {0..9} | xargs -n 3 -I % echo % /dest
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 /dest
```

I was hoping for behaviour like this:

```
$ echo {0..9} | xargs -n 3 -I % echo % /dest
0 1 2 /dest
3 4 5 /dest
6 7 8 /dest
9 /dest
```

Is this possible with `xargs`? I don't have GNU Parallel on my machines.

Comment: From you last sentence it seems you are aware that this can easily be solved with GNU Parallel. Can you elaborate on why you do not have GNU Parallel on your machines? Are any of the reasons covered by https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Comment: @OleTange I'm working on a script that runs on a large cluster of Jenkins worker machines. These are spun up on demand (so extra tools installed don't persist), and I don't have root on them.

Comment: @WilfredHuges But what stops you from installing without root access using one of the methods described on https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mv` command (at least from Linux coreutils) has the convenient `-t` flag that perfectly matches this use case:

```
find /foo -name 'bar*' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs mv -t /dest
```

Above also supports keeping any weirdo filename without filename *massaging*:

```
find /foo -name 'bar*' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /dest
```

If for whatever reason you want to use mv as usual, below could also work (i.e. use a `sh` *scriptlet* to "consume" all arguments (`$@`)):

```
find /foo -name 'bar*' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs sh -c 'mv "$@" /dest' --
```

Comment: Bingo! That works as expected, thanks. Note that `-t` isn't available on BSDs (e.g. OS X) but for Linux this is perfect.

Comment: This would break if any _directory_ matched the pattern, also the first and last would break if any name contained newlines or spaces.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you would do:

```
find /foo -name 'bar*' |
  parallel -X echo mv {} /dest
```

This works for file names containing ', " and space. If the file names contain '\n' then you have to resort to:

```
find /foo -name 'bar*' --print0 |
  parallel -0 -X echo mv {} /dest
```

If you do not have GNU Parallel on your machine and you do not have rights to install software as root, you can make a personal installation:

```
wget https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/parallel/parallel-20180422.tar.bz2
bzip2 -dc parallel-20180422.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -
cd parallel-20180422
./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install
```

Or you can use `--embed` on a machine that has GNU Parallel and then copy the resulting script to you other machine:

```
parallel --embed > new_script
# Change the end of new_script
# Copy new_script to the other machine
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for regular files with `find`, you should use `-type f`, or you may find directories. There is no need to use `xargs` here as you already have that ability built into `find`.

With GNU `mv`:

```
find /foo -type f -name 'bar*' -exec mv -t /dest {} +
```

This would not detect that a destination file with the same name already existed.  To do that, use

```
find /foo -type f -name 'bar*' -exec sh -c '
    for name do
        destname="/dest/${name##*/}"
        if [ ! -f "$destname" ]; then
            mv "$name" "$destname"
        else
            printf '%s exists already, will not copy %s\n' "$destname" "$name" >&2
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

This would refuse to move files that would overwrite files in `/dest` (and report these).

These commands will work with all valid Unix filenames.